Why Is My Weight Painting Black?
I can't paint this model. My weight painting is Black. Why?

This is my file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_VHAp8aFk5-p522MYeaY93SwWz_b5udG/view?usp=sharing
i cannot make or brush this to blue


It looks like you can weight paint as we can see red as well, black means 0 weight if you have enabled the option in the Weight Paint Overlays panel, but maybe share your file so that we can check?

Where are two parts in your question.
Why my Weights are black?
This is actually answered by moonbots, You have zero weights option enabled:

But it is not affect on why you can't paint. It just shows points with 0 weight, so that you can easily distinguish between 0.01 and 0 (It is important sometimes)
Why I can't paint?
This is because of brush settings. You have selected Add mode, in this case it can only add weight. But your weight is 0, so it is nothing to add. In this case, you should change brush to Mix mode:

Mix mode is the most common brush for painting weight, so I don't recommend you to change it, unless you definitely know what you are doing.
Wait, I still can't paint
Sure. This is because auto-normalize option is on. In this case, you can't remove weight if this weight is used only in this vertex group. Auto-normalize ensures that all deforming vertex groups add up to 100% while painting. When this option is turned off, then all weights of a vertex can have any value between 0 and 100%. However, when the option is on, in one vertex group it can add up to 100% only if it is 100%.

i can not find weight paint overlays icon

oh i see it, but i did this for the first steps but is not working :/

have you set brush to Mix mode?

I wouldn't say the issue is the brush choice, but the understanding of how brushes work. No matter if you use the Mix or Add, if you put your brush weight to 0 and expect to have full red, you will always have issues. With the Add brush, you "add" your brush weight value to your current vertex group. But since it is set to 0, you are asking Blender to add 0. Changing the brush weight to any other value would work just fine. With the Mix or Draw, it "draws" the weight as your brush weight (taking the brush falloff into account). With a brush weight of 0, you will draw weights of 0.

Can you explain by video recording, sr for make this thing go hard

https://youtu.be/X1jQ71Pg6SU

Thank You!! This Saved my life<3
